# EF Core 5 Transaction Deadlock with multiple simultaneous bulk MERGE statements

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, entity-framework-core, deadlock

I have an application which runs multiple threads to insert data into a SQL Server 2017 database table using EF Core 5.

The C# code for inserting the domain model entities using EF Core 5 is as follows:

```
using (var ctx = this.dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    //ctx.Database.AutoTransactionsEnabled = false;
    foreach (var rootEntity in request.RootEntities)
    {
        ctx.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(rootEntity, node =>
        {
            if ((request.EntityTypes != null && request.EntityTypes.Contains(node.Entry.Entity.GetType()))
                || rootEntity == node.Entry.Entity)
            {
                if (node.Entry.IsKeySet)
                    node.Entry.State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
                else
                    node.Entry.State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Added;
            }
        });
    }
    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Each thread is responsible for instantiating its own DbContext instance hence the use of dbContextFactory.

Some example SQL generated for the INSERT (MERGE) is as follows:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([OrderId] bigint, [_Position] [int]);
MERGE [dbo].[Orders] USING (
VALUES (@p0, 0),
(@p1, 1),
(@p2, 2),
...
(@43, 41)) AS i ([SomeColumn],  _Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([SomeColumn])
VALUES (i.[SomeColumn])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[OrderId], i._Position
INTO @inserted0;

SELECT [t].[OrderId] FROM [dbo].[Orders] t
INNER JOIN @inserted0 i ON ([t].[OrderId] = [i].[OrderId])
ORDER BY [i].[_Position];
```

As these threads frequently run at the same time I get the following SQL exception:

```
Transaction (Process ID 99) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

EF Core implicitly sets the isolation level to READ COMMITTED.

Using SQL Profiler the transaction deadlock was caused by the following:

[image]

My concerns:

1. Frustratingly, the SQL generated by EF Core includes two statements: a MERGE, and then a SELECT.  I do not understand the purpose of the SELECT given the identities of the primary key are available from the @inserted0 table variable.  Given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117330/978139), the MERGE statement in isolation would be sufficient enough to make this atomic.

I believe it is this SELECT which is causing the transaction deadlock.

2. I tried to resolve the problem by using READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT to avoid the conflict with the primary key lookup, however I still got the same error even though this isolation level should avoid locks and use row versioning instead.

My attempt at solving the problem:

The only way I could find to solve this problem was to explicitly prevent a transaction being started by EF Core, hence the following code:

```
ctx.Database.AutoTransactionsEnabled = false;
```

I have tested this numerous times and haven't received a transaction deadlock.  Given the logic is merely inserting new records I believe this can be done.

Does anyone have any advice to fixing this problem?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why Just do not insert to the same table by different threads?

Comment: Because EF core has automatically translated this into a MERGE not an INSERT. A MERGE of batches of 40 records is faster than 40 individual INSERT statements. Unless there is an option in EF Core to bulk insert using an individual sql statement??

Comment: I know why it translates to MERGE. Trying to figure out how to avoid that. Which kind of data do you insert? Maybe you need just `BulkCopy` via available extensions?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issues with INSERT (MERGE) statements on multiple threads. We didn't want to enable the EnableRetryOnFailure() option for all transactions, so we wrote the following DbContent extension method.

```
  public static async Task<TResult> SaveWithRetryAsync<TResult>(this DbContext context,
                                                                  Func<Task<TResult>> bulkInsertOperation,
                                                                  Func<TResult, Task<bool>> verifyBulkOperationSucceeded,
                                                                  IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Unspecified,
                                                                  int retryLimit = 6,
                                                                  int maxRetryDelayInSeconds = 30)
    {
        var existingTransaction = context.Database.CurrentTransaction?.GetDbTransaction();
        if (existingTransaction != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot run {nameof(SaveWithRetryAsync)} inside a transaction");

        if (context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "DbContext should be saved before running this action to revert only the changes of this action in case of a concurrency conflict.");
        }

        const int sqlErrorNrOnDuplicatePrimaryKey = 2627;
        const int sqlErrorNrOnSnapshotIsolation = 3960;
        const int sqlErrorDeadlock = 1205;
        int[] sqlErrorsToRetry = { sqlErrorNrOnDuplicatePrimaryKey, sqlErrorNrOnSnapshotIsolation, sqlErrorDeadlock };

        var retryState = new SaveWithRetryState<TResult>(bulkInsertOperation);

        // Use EF Cores connection resiliency feature for retrying (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency)
        // Usually the IExecutionStrategy is configured DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(..., options.EnableRetryOnFailure()).
        // In ASP.NET, the DbContext is configured in Startup.cs and we don't want this retry behaviour everywhere for each db operation.
        var executionStrategyDependencies = context.Database.GetService<ExecutionStrategyDependencies>();
        var retryStrategy = new CustomSqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy(executionStrategyDependencies, retryLimit, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxRetryDelayInSeconds), sqlErrorsToRetry);

        try
        {
            var result = await retryStrategy.ExecuteInTransactionAsync(
                retryState,
                async (state, cancelToken) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var r = await state.Action();

                        await context.SaveChangesAsync(false, cancelToken);

                        if (state.FirstException != null)
                        {
                            Log.Logger.Warning(
                                $"Action passed to {nameof(SaveWithRetryAsync)} failed {state.NumberOfRetries} times " +
                                $"(retry limit={retryLimit}, ThreadId={Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}).\nFirst exception was: {state.FirstException}");
                        }

                        state.Result = r;
                        return r;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        context.RevertChanges();
                        state.NumberOfRetries++;
                        state.FirstException ??= ex;
                        state.LastException = ex;

                        throw;
                    }
                },
                (state, cancelToken) => verifyBulkOperationSucceeded(retryState.Result),
                context.GetSupportedIsolationLevel(isolationLevel));

            context.ChangeTracker.AcceptAllChanges();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"DB Transaction in {nameof(SaveWithRetryAsync)} failed. " +
                $"Tried {retryState.NumberOfRetries} times (retry limit={retryLimit}, ThreadId={Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}).\n" +
                $"First exception was: {retryState.FirstException}.\nLast exception was: {retryState.LastException}",
                ex);
        }
    }
```

With the following CustomSqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy

```
 public class CustomSqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy : SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy
{
    public CustomSqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy(ExecutionStrategyDependencies executionStrategyDependencies, int retryLimit, TimeSpan fromSeconds, int[] sqlErrorsToRetry)
        : base(executionStrategyDependencies, retryLimit, fromSeconds, sqlErrorsToRetry)
    {
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception)
    {
        //SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy does not check the base exception, maybe a bug in EF core ?!
        return base.ShouldRetryOn(exception) || base.ShouldRetryOn(exception.GetBaseException());
    }
}
```

Helper class to save the current (retry) state:

```
private class SaveWithRetryState<T>
    {
        public SaveWithRetryState(Func<Task<T>> action)
        {
            Action = action;
        }

        public Exception FirstException { get; set; }
        public Exception LastException { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfRetries { get; set; }
        public Func<Task<T>> Action { get; }
        public T Result { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, the extension method can be used as follow. The code will try to add the bulk multiple times (5).

```
 await _context.SaveWithRetryAsync(
            // method to insert the bulk
            async () =>
            {
                var listOfAddedItems = new List<string>();
                foreach (var item in bulkImport)
                {
                    listOfAddedItems.Add(item.Guid);
                    await context.Import.AddAsync(item);
                }

                return listOfAddedItems;
            },
            // method to check if the bulk insert was successful
            listOfAddedItems =>
            {

                if (listOfAddedItems == null)
                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                return _context.Import.AsNoTracking().AnyAsync(x => x.Guid == listOfAddedItems.First());
            },
            IsolationLevel.Snapshot,
            5, // max retry attempts
            100); // max retry time
```

For background information why this can happen, have a look at this discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21899